# Scope in Loops in C++

Tags: c++, loops, scope

This is a very specific case but I am new to C++ and do not understand the output of this program I have written for the project euler website.

```
int x = 999;
int y = 999;
string result;

while (x > 320)
  {
    while(y > 320)
      {
        int inttoconvert = (x*y);
        cout<<inttoconvert<<"<-----This is product"<<endl;
        string result;
        ostringstream convert;
        convert << inttoconvert;
        result = convert.str();

        if (result[0] == result[5] && result[1] == result[4] && result[2] == result[3])
          {
            cout<<"The largest palindrome of 2 3-digit numbers is  "<<result<<endl;
            y = 0;
            x = 0;
          }
        else
          { 
            cout<<y<<endl;
            y--;
          }
      }//end while
    cout<<"this is x---->"<<x<<endl;
    x--;

  }//end while
```

The output shows that x decrements only after y has decremented to 321, but then it decrements repeatedly and the program does not enter the second while loops again.

I am starting to get suspicious about visual express

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Once `y <= 320`, `y` is never increased again, so there is never any reason for the code to enter the inner loop more than once.

Comment: This is not a scoping issue, but a logic/algorithm issue.

Comment: The mistake is in your code, not the compiler.

Comment: in 99.9999% of the cases it is your own code that is wrong and not the compiler - there are tens of thousands of people running the compiler everyday but only one (presumably) who wrote your code.

Answer (score 2):

The program won't enter the second while loop again because nested loops all share the same scope. `y` won't be reset again after it exits the second while loop. So once `y` can't satisfy the inner loop's conditions, it won't go into it, it'll just skip it and go straight into decrementing `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `y` at the beginning of the `x` loop, not outside both loops.

```
int x = 999;
string result;

while (x > 320)
  {
    int y = 999;
    while(y > 320)
```

You could also use `for` loops instead of `while`

```
for (int x = 999; x > 320; x--) {
   for (int y = 999; y > 320; y--) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you never reset y, I believe that is why you are having a problem

Answer (score 0):

enters loop.
after the (y > 320) loop, y equals 320.
exits (y is greater than 320) loop.
x is decremented to 998.
checks the (x > 320) condition again.
it is true, so it tries to do the (y > 320) loop again.
y still equals 320, so it cannot ever enter that loop again.
so, it will keep skipping that loop and decrementing x.